# Regarding .Net Windows Authentication

Tags: .net, session, authentication

I have a web application which is set up to use windows authentication. This is used by people across the state. These users are not in our AD and are authenticated against the database when they try to log in. After a successful login, the resources to which the use has access to are stored as bits in the session.

For each subsequent request we check the session variables to see if it is valid request and if the user is authorized to access the resource. We do not use Forms authentication.

As the number of users grow I am worried about the size of the session state. How do we better handle the authentication/authorization without the use of session variables? This is a .Net Web Application using 2.0.

Comment: Your title does not match your question at all. Anyway a few bits per user will not be a problem for your session storage.

Comment: Agreed, will change the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few bits per user is not something that will take too much memory and affect the scalability of your website. Well, unless you have thousands of bits per user.

However, the real performance hit can be coming from the code that is calculating all those resources accessible by each user. If that code is a bit heavy, you can consider spreading out the load:

Once the user is authenticated, just save one value that indicates the user's role. Then every time you need to check if the user has access to a specific resource, you retrieve the role-value from the session and use it to determine whether the user has access or not.

Answer (score 0):

If the size becomes an issue then you can persist the bits and do a lookup as needed - this may sound expensive, but some caching could help out considerably so that active users are not continuously hitting the persisted storage & non active users are not taking up memory with their bits.